# Is there any way to get the result of XCTAssertTrue()?

Tags: swift, xcode, boolean, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I would like to know if there is a way to get the values returned by XCode’s `XCTAssertTrue`, `XCTAssertEqual` and `XCTAssertFalse`.

Comment: The actual method declarations don't suggest that they do return a value at all.

Comment: Ok ,so in case a test fails due to assert , how is the failure actually generated ?

Comment: @Khazana What do you mean? Describe what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @MichałMyśliwiec, I want the result i,e. pass or fail , of each test case so that I can make an  API call to TestRail( a testcase management tool) to update my test results.

Comment: Look into test listeners or observers. I don't know how good the support is lately, but it was in old XCTest.

Comment: @JonReid, I tried using an observer, as seen from solutions posted in StackOverflow...didn't work though. But maybe I'm using it wrong, a working example would be nice :)

Comment: I'd keep pursuing test observers. That's what they're for.

Answer (score 0):

XCTestCase has a method

`- (void)recordFailureWithDescription:(NSString *)description inFile:(NSString *)filePath atLine:(NSUInteger)lineNumber expected:(BOOL)expected;`

According to the documentation assertions use this method to record failures. Maybe you can override this method to call your API.